# How can I correctly implement the methods in my class?

Tags: java, arrays, interface, iterator

I have a class `SimpHisto` that takes in an array of generic type `SL`, and returns the size and the count of a specific element of that array. My code is provided down below.

```
public class SimpHisto<SL> implements Histo<SL>, Iterable<SL> {
    DT[] items;

    public SimpHisto() {
    }

    public SimpHisto(SL[] items) {

        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount(SL item) {
        var n = 0;
        Iterator<SL> L = this.iterator();
        while (L.hasNext()) {
            for (DT dt : items) {
                if (dt == item) {
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<SL> iterator() {

        return new Iterate();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTotalCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    private class Iterate implements Iterator<SL> {
        int index = 0;
        boolean lastRemoved = false;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (index < items.length);
        }

        @Override
        public SL next() {
            if (index <= items.length)
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No element at index");
            SL object = items[index];
            index++;
            lastRemoved = false;
            return object;
        }
    }
```

After I tried to run my code using the snippet down below...

```
public class SimpleHistogramTest {

    @Test
    public void testHistogram() {
        Character[] s = {'a','b','c','a'};
        Histo<Character> h = new SimpHisto<>(s);
        Iterator<Character> iter = h.iterator();
        int elemCount = 0;
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            iter.next();
            elemCount++;
        }

        assertEquals(3, elemCount);
        assertEquals(2, h.getCount('a'));
        assertEquals(1, h.getCount('b'));
        assertEquals(1, h.getCount('c'));
        assertEquals(4, h.getTotalCount());
    }
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test FAILED

No element at index
```

Can someone please explain what's wrong with my code and provide any explanations on solutions?

Thank you

P.S. this is interface `Histo` which is implemented by `SimpHisto`

```
public interface Histo<DT> extends Iterable<DT> {

    public int getTotalCount();
    public int getCount(DT item);
    public void setCount(DT item, int count);
}
```

Comment: debug your test and see where it fails

Comment: Think about `if (index <= items.length)`

Comment: @英語は苦手 what do u suggest I change in my code then? can you please explain

Comment: `getCount()` does not call `L.next()`, so it may loop infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your `Iterate`.
You throw that exception `if (index <= items.length)`.
`index` starts with 0 so this is always `true`.
You only have to change to `>=`

As mentioned by 英語は苦手 your `while` in `getCount` does not call `next`.
Since you iterate over the items directly I would prefer to remove the `Iterator` at all.
And a `Stream` may increase readability:

```
return (int) Stream.of(this.items)
    .filter(dt -> dt == item)
    .count();
```

EDIT: without `Stream`-API you can iterate over your `items` directly:

```
for (SL dt : this.items) {
    if (dt == item) {
        n++;
    }
}
```

If you want to use the `Iterator` you have to call `next`

```
while (L.hasNext()) {
    SL dt = L.next();
    if (dt == item) {
        n++;
    }
}
```

BTW: why `assertEquals(3, elemCount);`? There are 4 elements

Comment: because elemcount starts from 0 so it goes 0, 1,2 and 3

Comment: also is it possible to show the iterator way of doing this, since I want to learn that way first. I haven't learnt about streams yet and I would like to start with iterator first, thank you

Comment: @Nutnicha `iter.hasNext()` will return `true` 4 times as well as `elemCount++;` so this will be 4 ;) I modified my answer getting rid of `Stream`